# Accelerated in reverse, quickly with handbrake still on. What damage to manual van?

Tags: manual-transmission, handbrake

Accelerated in reverse from a muddy patch with the handbrake still on. Realised the problem when accelerating but going no where. Tried again with the handbrake off and noise while reversing.
What damage have I done?

Comment: Does the noise appear to be coming from the rear wheels?

Comment: Difficult to say. Can we have photos of the rear brakes without the wheel? What car? Please specify: Front wheel drive, rear wheel drive or all wheel drive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handbrake on while reversing](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/74864/handbrake-on-while-reversing)